# Selecting specific solutions from a differential equation using DSolve with difficult boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, boundary-condition-at-infinity

Let's suppose I want to solve Laplace's equation in Axial Symmetry:
$$
\nabla^2\psi=\partial^2_{\rho}\psi+\partial^2_{z}\psi+\frac{1}{\rho}\partial_{\rho}\psi=0,
$$
for some function $\psi=\psi(\rho,z)$, where $\rho\in[0,\infty)$ and $z\in(-\infty,\infty)$. There are quite a few examples of how to solve Laplace's equation using `DSolve[]` in the documentation, but as it seems, only for finite regions or with finitely-placed boundaries. But there are solutions (very important in physics) for example
$$
\psi=-\frac{m}{\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}}\,,\quad\psi=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\rho^2+(z-l)^2}+\sqrt{\rho^2+(z+l)^2}-2l}{\sqrt{\rho^2+(z-l)^2}+\sqrt{\rho^2+(z+l)^2}+2l}\right)
$$
for some constants $(m,l)$. The first describes a point source, and the second describes a finite line source.

I am interested in how one might obtain these solutions from `DSolve[]` by inputting Laplace's equation and appropriate boundary conditions. One would need to set a boundary at infinity (as in an infinite Euclidean distance from the source) where ($\psi=0$) and then somehow adding a boundary where the source is located ($\psi=-\infty$).

I am interested how this may be done in general, not just for Laplace's equation, so making variable substitutions may not always be possible I guess.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned that you want a boundary condition at infinity, but you did not specify is $\rho$ goes to infinity, or $z$ or both.

Comment: Here $\rho$ ranges from 0 to $\infty$ and $z$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. When I say that the boundary is ``at infinity'', I mean at any infinite Euclidean distance away from the source.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your post with these details, so people have the full picture

Comment: `GreenFunction`?